# Using jmockit, how to avoid the impact between two cases?

Tags: unit-testing, jmockit

I have two classes, the first class:

```
public class FirstClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FirstClass.class);

    public void action(){
        LOG.info("FirstClass.action.");
    }
}
```

the second class:

```
public class SecondClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SecondClass.class);

    public void action(){
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();
        firstClass.action();
    }
}
```

I will write unit test for these two classes, the first class unit test:

```
public class FirstClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testAction(){
        FirstClass firstClass = new FirstClass();
        firstClass.action();
    }
}
```

the second class unit test:

```
public class SecondClassTest {
    @Mocked
    private Logger LOG;

    @Mocked
    private FirstClass firstClass;

    @Test
    public void testAction(){
        SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();
        secondClass.action();
    }
}
```

About the second class unit test, As the second class depend on the first class, so I mocked the first class, at same time I also mocked Logger class.

I add a suite class to run these two classes:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({SecondClassTest.class ,FirstClassTest.class})
public class TestAll {
}
```

When I run this suite class, it throw the follow exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:663)
at steve.test.jmockit.issues.mocklog4j.FirstClass.action(FirstClass.java:12)
at steve.test.jmockit.issues.mocklog4j.FirstClassTest.testAction(FirstClassTest.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

From this trace log, the LOG of first class has been mocked. but in fact I don't mock Logger in FirstClassTest class.

But when I changed this suite class, firstly run FirstClassTest.class, and then run SecondClassTest.class. all cases are successful.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({FirstClassTest.class ,SecondClassTest.class})
public class TestAll {
}
```

How to fix this issue and ensure that there is no effect between the two cases? Thanks!

Comment: About 'SecondClassTest', Firstly the 'Logger' is mocked, the 'FirstClass' is mocked too. so the "FirstClass.LOG" will be mocked. Because the 'FirstClass.LOG' is static field, when run FirstClassTest.class and execute 'LOG.info("FirstClass.action.")', the field 'LOG' is mocked instance, but the 'Logger' don't be mocked. it will throw NullPointerException.

This issue is same as '@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization=true) private FirstClass firstClass'

Answer (score 0):

I ran the first Suite and do not see the issue you describe.  My output is:

```
Jul 09, 2015 12:00:59 AM First action
INFO: FirstClass.action.
```

I'm using JMockit 1.18; JDK 1.8; JUnit 4.12

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because both tests call `LOG.info(...)` on the *same* `LOG` instance, with this being an *uninitialized* instance (ie, an instance with all of its reference fields `null`).

The reason `LOG` holds an uninitialized instance is that the `Logger` class got mocked when the first test was executed. The class gets unmocked before the second test runs, but that doesn't change the state of the `LOG` object. So, when the second call to `LOG.info(...)` occurs, it is not mocked, but attempts to use `Logger` fields which are still `null`, causing the NPE.

The way to avoid the problem is to ensure the `LOG` field gets initialized before the `Logger` class is mocked. This can be done, for example, by adding a `@BeforeClass` method which instantiates `FirstClass` (since it holds the `LOG` field in question).

Comment: `The class gets unmocked before the second test runs, but that doesn't change the state of the LOG object.` Since the `Logger` is not mocked in the second test runs, the variable should be initialized with a static keyword. How it could be null?